# Cypress send image in request

Tags: api, cypress

I am trying to send image as a part of POST request, any idea how i can do this?

Request:

```
    cy.request({
    method: 'post', 
    url: '/some/url', 
    body: {
    'name': data.Name,
    'slug': data.Slug,
    'new_preview_image': 'images/test.jpeg',
    },
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json'
      },
      auth: {
          'bearer': ''
      }
});
```

That is the request i am trying to send, but for image i am getting response

```
Body: {
"message": "The new preview image must be an image."}
```

Comment: We really can't help you because we have no idea what kind of data (and request) your `/some/url` endpoint is expecting and you haven't told us.

Comment: Normally images and files (e.g. from `<input type="file"/>`) are POSTed as separate binaries in a `multipart/form-data` request - but it looks like you're submitting JSON. JSON is textual and cannot contain binary data.